# Backbone.js async calls

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I've been searching about this and haven't found an answer yet.

I found out that you can use `async: true` when calling `fetch` on Backbone, which isn't mentioned in its website. Can other methods, such as `save`, `create`, etc., be used with `async` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Backbone.sync documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) :

> `Backbone.sync` is the function that Backbone calls every time it
>   attempts to read or save a model to the server. By default, it uses
>   `jQuery.ajax` to make a RESTful JSON request and returns a jqXHR.

It means you can use all [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) options on you requests, and you can indeed set an `async` option (defaults to `true`) on `save`/`create`